# Call Userform based on Userform Value in cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with the following values:

[image]

Now, I would like to call the Userform in column H based on the value in column G, but I can't work out how to call the Userform based on the cell value. The error occurs in line

```
form.Name = wsControls.Cells(loop2, 8).Value
```

Here is my code:

```
Sub Check_Scenarios()
Dim wsAbsatz As Worksheet
Dim wsControls As Worksheet
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim loop1 As Long
Dim loop2 As Long
Dim lngKW As Long
Dim form As UserForm

Set wsAbsatz = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Production")
Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Set wsControls = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Controls")

lngKW = wsControls.Cells(1, 2).Value + 2

If lngKW = 3 Then
    Exit Sub
End If


For loop1 = wsControls.Cells(10, 2).Value To wsControls.Cells(19, 2).Value Step 10
    If wsData.Cells(loop1 + 3, lngKW).Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox (wsData.Cells(loop1 + 3, lngKW).Value)
        For loop2 = 2 To 16
            If wsData.Cells(loop1 + 3, lngKW).Value = wsControls.Cells(loop2, 7).Value Then
                form.Name = wsControls.Cells(loop2, 8).Value 'error occurs here
                form.Show
            End If
        Next loop2
    End If
Next loop1

End Sub
```

Project:

[image]

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the specific error you're getting?

Comment: Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91)

Comment: @Mat'sMug - I would vote for `91 - object variable or with-variable`

Comment: Good guess @Vityata. Unfortunately, I am struggling with getting your answer to work.

Comment: @Vityata I know, it was more of a nudge to [edit] the information into the question =)

Comment: @VBAPete - what do you mean, when you use `Name` as a property of a `UserForm`? This property does not exist as a built-in one. I suppose, that you mean `Caption`. And to make your code work *somehow*, simply add *New* in `Dim form As New UserForm`.

Comment: When I use `Dim form As New UserForm` I get error `Invalid use of New keyword`.

Comment: You can't `New` up the base `UserForm` class that's why.

Comment: If I remove `New`, I get error `Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91)`

Comment: @VBAPete - give a screenshot of your Project. Probably `UserForm` is named `UserForm1` or something similar. In this case write `Dim form as New UserForm1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't "call" a userform. You *instantiate* it, and then you `Show` it.

`UserForm` is the "base class" from which all userforms are derived. See there *is* inheritance in VBA, only not with custom classes.

So you have a `UserForm2` class, a `UserForm3` class, a `UserForm4` class, and so on.

These classes need to be *instantiated* before they can be used.

```
Dim theForm As UserForm
Set theForm = New UserForm2
theForm.Show

Set theForm = New UserForm3
theForm.Show

'...
```

So what you need is a way to parameterize this `Set theForm = New ?????` part.

And you can't. Because whatever you're going to do, the contents of a cell is going to be a string, and there's no way you can get an instance of a `UserForm3` out of a `String` that says `"UserForm3"`.

Make a *factory* function that does the translation:

```
Public Function CreateForm(ByVal formName As String) As UserForm
    Select Case formName
        Case "UserForm1"
            Set CreateForm = New UserForm1
        Case "UserForm2"
            Set CreateForm = New UserForm2
        Case "UserForm3"
            Set CreateForm = New UserForm3
        '...
    End Select
End Function
```

And then call that function to get your form object:

```
Set form = CreateForm(wsControls.Cells(loop2, 8).Value)
If Not form Is Nothing Then form.Show
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to assign a *Name* to a *blueprint*. These are two errors.

You have to initialize your blueprint as something. Like this:

`Dim form As New UserForm`
Then, most probably your `UserForm` does not have a property called `Name`. It is called `Caption`. Thus it is like this:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim uf As New UserForm1 'judging from your screenshot
    uf.Caption = "Testing"
    uf.Show

End Sub
```

**Disclaimer:**
There is a better way to work with UserForms, not abusing the blueprint, although almost every VBA book shows this `UserForm.Show` method (in fact every single one I have read so far).

If you have the time and the OOP knowledge [implement the ideas from here](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) - or from [my interpretation of the ideas](http://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-the-perfect-userform-in-vba/). There was also a documentation article about it in StackOverflow, but it was deleted with the whole documentation idea.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can I call the userform by its name rather than by its caption? I need to use the same caption for all 5 user forms.

Comment: @VBAPete you don't seem to be understanding what this code is doing. It's not *calling a userform by caption*, it's creating a new instance of `UserForm`, setting its `Caption`, and then `Show`ing it... which doesn't quite answer your question, but I'd warmly recommend you read the links given (disclaimer: I wrote the first, and authored the documentation the second is inspired from).

Comment: Nice site you have there :)